# Link that pass parameter values to app / play store download

Tags: swift, kotlin, google-play, app-store, ios-universal-links

I need to create a link that will open on App Store for iOS and on Play Store for Android.

This link will also have a parameter that I need to get in case the user downloads the app.

I know this can be done with Universal Link, but I'm not sure if using Universal Links is overkill.

Is there any other way this can be achieved?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?